# Typescript builds files with incorrect path in monorepo

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have an example monorepo with 3 packages: back, front and shared. With the following folder structure:

```
root
├── back
│   ├── dist
│   ├── src
│       ├── test.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── front
├── shared
│   ├── dist
│   ├── src
│       ├── my-enum.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

test.ts

```
import { MyEnum } from '@test/shared/src/my-enum'
setTimeout(() => console.log(2 == MyEnum.B), 1000, 1)
```

my-enum.ts

```
export enum MyEnum{ A = 1, B, C }
```

When I build the back package typescript generates in the dist folder a `test.js` file with `var my_enum_1 = require("@test/shared/src/my-enum");`, however the compiled files of the shared package are in the `dist` folder, not in `src`, so if I try to run with `node` I get the following error:

```
Error: Qualified path resolution failed: we looked for the following paths, but none could be accessed.

Source path: E:\Repository\workspace_test\shared\src\my-enum
Not found: E:\Repository\workspace_test\shared\src\my-enum
Not found: E:\Repository\workspace_test\shared\src\my-enum.js
Not found: E:\Repository\workspace_test\shared\src\my-enum.json
Not found: E:\Repository\workspace_test\shared\src\my-enum.node
```

If I use `ts-node` instead of `node` it works, but that's not how I'd like to run this after deploy. I assume there's something I need to change in my `tsconfig.json` files but I can't find out what it is, other related SO questions I could find weren't very helpful.

I uploaded an example repo on [github](https://github.com/janilson-123/example_workspace_so) to make things easier to anyone willing to help, but here are my ts.config files:

Root:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Back:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src"
    },
    "references": [
        { "path": "../shared" }
    ]
}
```

Shared:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "rootDir": "src"
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to work when you use `"rootDir": "."`.

Comment: are you sure? to me it didn't, the path on the compiled file remains the same `require("@test/shared/src/my-enum")`, and it still fails the import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so to fix this I had to change the `package.json` instead of the `tsconfig.json`. Making the `main` field in `shared/package-json` point to the dist folder doesn't do  anything for some reason, but the `exports` field actually works, so creating an alias there solved the issue.

So for this example project it would be something like `"exports": { "./src/my-enum": "./dist/src/my-enum.js" }`.